# NPM script Webpack --json : JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-bundle-analyzer

We have an angular 5 project which has a problem with size. On load of the app, when there isn't much of anything, we have 95MB in memory.
I'm trying to analyze it and use `webpack-bundle-analyzer`.

I've read that adding `new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin()` into `webpack.config` should help, so I did and it helped (from 95 to 76MB).

But when I run build with stats after that `npm run build:stats > stats.json`
(`"build:stats": "webpack --profile --json --config webpack.config.buildserver.js"`) I get this message
**FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory**

Before adding the plugin, the `stats.json` file had around 390 000 lines of json object.

I found that there is a memory flag for node scripts `--max_new_space_size` but I can't find anything similar for webpack script.

I'm not sure what to look for, could anyone help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known bug, you can check this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5618) for more details and also try to install [this npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/increase-memory-limit) and run before you build and after npm install.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try it out and if it works I'll mark you as a god. Or something.

Comment: You can create an npm script as `fix: increase-memory-limit` so if you need it's easier to execute.

Comment: Yeah, I did that :)

Answer (score 1):

To set Node.js flags one can use [`NODE_OPTIONS` env variable](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#node_optionsoptions).

For example, building stats in webpack version 4:

```sh
NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=4096" webpack --json > stats.json
```